# grab frequent username from 'last' command in unix - with exceptions

Tags: macos, unix, sed, awk

If I run this on OS X:

```
last -10 | awk '{print $1}'
```

I get:
chop
chop
chop
chrihopk
reboot
shutdown
chop
chop
chop
chrihopk

How do I use sed or awk to obtain the most frequent user 'chop'?

ADDITIONAL EDIT TO QUESTION:
Our local admin account interferes with the results (username: support) and often we have a new starter on a client box.
How could I modify

```
last -1
```

to omit the following and return the last valid username:

support
reboot
shutdown

Thanks

Comment: Hi earcar - sorry, you are quite right but I'm still testing these solutions and am now poised to add to the question. I'm juggling projects just now but have come back to this. Edit is above.
Thanks for your input. Chris

Comment: You should use the code or blockquote features to format your question to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your edit, leave off the numeric argument to `last` and use `egrep` like this:

```
last | egrep -v 'support|reboot|shutdown'
```

then pipe that into `awk` as in the other answers.

Answer (score 9):

```
bash$ last -10 | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

`sort -un` does something, but I'm not sure what...

```
bash$ echo -e 'bob\nbob\ncat\ncat\ncat\ndog'
bob
bob
cat
cat
cat
dog
bash$ echo -e 'bob\nbob\ncat\ncat\ncat\ndog' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
      3 cat
      2 bob
      1 dog
bash$ echo -e 'bob\nbob\ncat\ncat\ncat\ndog' | sort -un
bob
bash$ echo -e 'bob\nbob\ncat\ncat\ncat\ndog' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}'
cat
```

Comment: @earcar: You learn something new every day. Upon testing it, it seems to work... I'm confused about how it works, though, since I can find exactly zero documentation to say that it would do that... Is that a compatibility option from a million years ago?

Comment: @eacar: I knew about `sort -u`, and have used it where appropriate... Where is documented that `sort -un` behaves differently to `sort -n -u` ?

Comment: too much pipe chaining and ugly.

Comment: `sort -un` doesn't work for me on Mac OS X (GNU textutils 1.14)

Comment: @adam: I'm on osx 10.5 and it works: sort (GNU coreutils) 5.93 (no macports or similar)
@stobor: it doesn't make any difference in behaviour here between `-u -n` and `-un`.. what version of sort do you have?

Comment: @earcar: Yeah, you're right, I'm even more confused now. :-) `sort -n` is documented as sorting numerically. `sort -u` is documented as keeping only 1 copy of unique lines. How does that result in the combination of them outputting only 1 line?

Comment: Also, it seems to print the wrong line in the face of quotation marks. :-S

Comment: Hmm... Maybe it always fails?

Comment: I'm now confused too.. It seems to me that sort -un displays the first line of input.. It's very strange and incorrect! Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 6):

If you want

- a nice ascending-ordered list of users with number of logins (the `$0!~/^$/` stuff only assures blank lines will not be counted):

  ```
  last | awk '$0!~/^$/ {print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort
  ```
- username with logins number:

  append `| tail -1` to the code above.
- same as above in awk (faster):

  ```
  last | awk '{a[$1]++}END{m=0;for(v in a){if(a[v]>m){m=a[v];u=v}}print m,u}'
  ```
- username only in awk:

  delete the last `m,` from the code above.

Comment: +1 for `sort -un` even though I don't know where it says what that combination does...

Comment: Perfect. The first option is exactly what I am after. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

just awk

```
last -10 |awk '{ user[$1]++}
END{
    t=0
    for(i in user){
        if (user[i]>t) {
            t=user[i]
            u=i
        }
    }
    print t,u
}'
```

with gawk, you can make use of the asort, asorti internal functions

Answer (score 1):

The following pipeline offers a starting point, which I'm certain could be optimized:

```
last | awk '{A[$1] += 1; for (v in A) print A[v],v}' | sort -ur | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pipe that into sort, you'll get an easily parsable list of data to find the most frequent user, although I don't know how to find that user without a scripting language.